# where to update Java JDK? (not how to install)

Tags: software-installation, updates, java, jdk, oracle

All the questions on here I've found are *how* to *install* JDK. I have JDK already, but Android Studio says it's outdated. I'm asking **where** I can update JDK.

"which java" in terminal gives /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java, but installing the tar file there does not update the JDK. Neither does installing in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle.

Thanks.

Comment: You update by (removing the older and) installing the newer version.

Comment: Did you install using apt or from a website online?

Comment: @Byte I have a folder named JRE in usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle. Do I just right click delete the JRE folder? Thanks

Comment: @ubashu I went to Oracle's site, downloaded the tar then ran sudo tar xvzf on it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you may find it easier to use webupd8's PPA. You can find more information at the launchpad page for the PPA. https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java. To add this PPA, run:

```bsh
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle  # to remove the current installation
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties  # to install the extra commands to add the apt repository
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java  # to add the PPA (accept the prompts)
sudo apt-get update  # to get the repository info from the PPA
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer  # to install the oracle java (version 8, what you previously had installed)
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default  # to set the newly installed java as default
```

In order to update, you can simply use your normal update procedure.

If you choose to continue with the downloading from Oracle method, you need to complete the following steps:

1. Remove the old installation.
2. Download the tarball and install it.

To remove the old installation, you can simply run in a terminal

```
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

And then use the same installation steps as you used previously. If you need help with this, please see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre).

Comment: Oh, I see. So Java 8 = "JDK 8u162"? And to update (from 8u77 to 8u162 in my case), I just have to delete Java 8 altogether and then reinstall it altogether?

Comment: Correct. Unless you choose to go the PPA method...